# List directories and their files grouping them on one line for tokenization

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I want to group the directory name with their files in bash script.
For example if I type `ls /home/maindir/*`

I get `home/maindir/dir1: file1 file2\n file3
     home/maindir/dir2: file1 file2`

The directories with files are not separated by a specified delimiter because there are cases that file1 and file2, in the same directory, have a newline beetween them, so I want to tokenize with a delimiter the directory name and its file list all on one line.
Example output with newline delimiter:

```
home/maindir/dir1: file1 file2 file3\n
home/maindir/dir2: file1 file2\n
home/maindir/dir3: file1 file2 file4\n
```

Comment: Is that actually the end goal, or is that just something you want to parse to do something else with? Because what you describe is possible, but a little messy to do; if you actually just want to parse it into some other form, there's probably a better way.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally used an unquoted interpolation trick. 
For example, if you have strings in a file, one per line, and you want them horizontalized, you don't have to use paste -

file named foo:

```
a
b
c
```

then you can say:

```
echo $(<foo)
```

and you get

```
a b c
```

But that could cause issues with filenames, especially if they have embedded special chars or whitespace.

Thanks to Gordon Davisson for a simple upgrade!

```
for d in /home/maindir/*    # includes full path each time
do [[ -d "$d" ]] || continue  # ignore nondirectories
   cd "$d"                    # go there to make filenames path-bare
   echo "$d:" * 
done
```

Note that this still includes subdirectories. Do you need to skip those?
If you want to be more careful -

```
for d in /charter/apps/*
do [[ -d "$d" ]] || continue
   cd "$d"
   dir="$d: "
   hit=0
   for f in *
   do if [[ -f "$f" ]]
      then hit=1
           dir="$dir $f "
      fi
   done
   (( $hit )) && printf "$dir\n"
done
```

This one should also work on files with embedded spaces &c.

Comment: This'll have trouble if directory names with spaces (or tabs or...), filenames with wildcards, etc. You'd be better off quoting all variable references, setting `nullglob`, and using `echo "$d:" *` to get the file list.

Comment: You should also quote a variable if it can be a path. That means you need to quote `$d` within your `if` statement, and when you run your `cd`.

Comment: I know there aren't subdirectory and there aren't filenames with wildcards or spaces.

Comment: Still a good policy unless you have a good specific reason to avoid it.

Comment: @RobertSeaman `[[ ]]` doesn't require quoting, so `[[ -d $d ]]` wouldn't break even if there was whitespace or glob characters in `$d`. Quoting doesn't hurt, though.

Comment: That was news to me. Thanks, Benjamin.

Comment: That's news to me too! Thanks @BenjaminW.